# nzec error in spoj but working fine in eclipse

Tags: java

I am working on SPOJ Divisibility problem. The problem is that my code works fine on eclipse, but shows NZEC error when submitted in SPOJ. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = input2.nextInt();
        while(t>0){
            String s = input.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
            int upper = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int x= Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int y= Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            for(int i=0;i<upper;i++){
                if(i%x==0 && i%y!=0){
                    System.out.printf(i+" "); 
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            t--;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there might be a white space after the number of test cases in the input data (see the [working example](http://ideone.com/GrMOR7), and your (line 6):

```
int t = input2.nextInt();
```

does not eat it.

Advice: use the same method for reading input along the whole program to ensure that such an inconsistency will not crash your code.